# 3D Temperature Distribution Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to write a script in MATLAB to create a 3D Temperature Distribution plot for the following problem:

Three sides of a rectangular plate (a=5m, b=4m) are kept at a temperature of 0° and one side is kept at a temperature T1=80°.

[image]

Determine and plot the 3D temperature distribution T(x,y) in the plate.
The temperature distribution in the plate can be determined by solving the two-dimensional heat equations. For the given boundary conditions, it can be expressed analytically by a Fourier series as,

[image]

My problem is I am unfamiliar with plotting in MATLAB and a little daunted by the Fourier series and how you would code that.  My professor said we would need 3 for loops to properly accomplish what the problem is asking us to do.  So far I have:

```
%Plating Test
clear
clc
a=5;
b=4;
na=20;
nb=16;
k=100;
T1=80;

for i=1:1:na;
    for j=1:1:nb;
        T(i,j)=f(X(i,j) Y(i,j));

    end
end
```

But I am unsure how to proceed.  I believe there is more I need before the for loops, and I know the for loops themselves aren't done, but I am unsure how to proceed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are `X(i,j)` and `Y(i,j)`?

Comment: That's part of the example of code we will need that the professor provided, but she didn't explain what they were which is part of my confusion.

Comment: Hint: you need 3 (nested) loops, one to go over the values of `x` on `[0 a]`, one to go over the values of `y` on `'[0 b]`, and one to go over the values of `n` to go from `0` to a large number, approximating infinity.

Answer (score 0):

you need to solve the equation mentioned in 2D , T (x,y) , meaning temperature distrubition in x and y directions for the domain of size you can go in terms of area ( as only x and y are mentioned its FEM ( finite element method), if z is also placed into equ, you need to go with FVM ( finite volume methods ) . SOlutions is to discretize in the both directions ( quasi forming a coarse grid or rough grid and benchmark your grid size ( all will relatte to so called meshing))

Answer (score 0):

You understand that what you are trying to solve is actually just a 1D problem but calculated twice?

you can use newmann's rule to evaluate the problem:

Yg = Yx*Yy*Yz

where you calculate each Ys (s standing for any axis) with their corresponding Fo solution